# jQuery DOM event not working on Backbone View

Tags: jquery, dom, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

i have a view that every time is called re-renders the elements in the view, here is a code's piece:

```
Project.Views.CheckinScheduledView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'div',
id:'CheckinScheduledView',
className:'section',
checkinsHtml: '',

initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this);

    this.checkinsCollections = new Project.Collections.Checkins();

    this.checkinsCollections.on('reset', this.render);
    this.checkinsCollections.fetch();
},

events: {
    'click .scheduled_checkin a':'deleteCheckin'
},

render: function() {
    var that = this;

    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    if($('li.scheduled_checkin').length) {
        $('li.scheduled_checkin').each(function() {
            $(this).css('display','none').empty().remove();
        });
    }



    if(Project.InfoWindow.length) {
        Project.InfoWindow[0].close();
    }

    _.each(this.checkinsCollections.models, function(item) {
        that.renderLocation(item);
    });

    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    this.renderCheckins();
    return this;
},

refreshData: function() {
    this.checkinsCollections.fetch();
}
```

this is a case:

1. open home page
2. click on checkIn (current view code)
3. go back to home
4. the view render but adds the items to the list

images

First time i load the view
[image: first time i load the view]

let's say that i go to another view and now i come back to this view
[image: let's say that i go to another view and now i come back to this view]

and again :(
[image: and again]

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle/jsbin?

Comment: Btw probably ` $('li.scheduled_checkin').remove()` would work as well, since it has implicit iteration as in [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: @alonisser i tried that and won't work, here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rommelxcastro/Pnwp8/

Comment: sorry brow, the fiddle is no good since you don't supply any html. my guess you either have a typo in the class name, so the `each` function doesn't run. or that render isn't called

Comment: @alonisser if you see line 43, you can see where i create the html ;)

Comment: Where are the `li.scheduled_checkin` elements supposed to be? Anywhere in the DOM or within the view's `el`?

Comment: @muistooshort the li.scheduled_checkin are those boxes that say NEW, basically is the same model

Comment: You mean "same view"? Have you tried using `this.$(...)` instead of `$(...)` to localize the search to the view's `el`? Using `$(...)` assumes that what you want is in the DOM already and that might not be the case inside a Backbone `render` call.

Comment: @muistooshort i forget to mention, if i do a console.log($(this)) inside the each(function() {}) i can see the elements in the console, but the remove()/empty()/hide() is not working

Comment: @RommelCastro I was wrong sorry, no Typo and the Html is in the fiddle - and from you answered to @muistooshort I figure that the render function is called everytime (is it? because I suspect a problem in the initialize part, and if it isn't called everytime would prove that). maybe it's something simple as replacing `$(this) ` with `$.el.remove()` as most tuts show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your jsfiddle without working HTML example, at this function:

```
renderLocation: function(location) {
    this.checkinsHtml = this.checkinsHtml+'<li class="scheduled_checkin"><a data-id="'+location.attributes.scheduleId+'" href="#/checkin/" title="Delete: '+location.attributes.description+'">'+location.attributes.title+'</a></li>';
}
```

I guess that you forgot to reset this.checkinsHtml when re-render the view.

**Edit**: For the better way, you should render html from the template.

Example using Mustache.js

```
var template = '{{#models}}' +
               '<li class="scheduled_checkin">' +
                   '<a data-id="{{attributes.scheduleId}}" href="#/checkin/" title="Delete: {{attributes.description}}">{{attributes.title}}</a>' +
               '</li>' +
               '{{/models}}';
$('#scheduled_checkins .two-columns').html(Mustache.render(template, this.checkinsCollections));
```

Comment: i just found this solution a few min ago, i wanted to answer the question and i saw your reply, and yes this resolved the problem, thanks!